# How to provide a lambda mapping function as method parameter?

Tags: java, java-stream

It is possible to pass a lambda expression as a function parameter? Example as follows: I want to pass the "strategy" that extracts properties from list items. For not having to repeat the stream mapping over and over again.

```
List<MyObject> list;

list.stream().map(item -> item.field1)).collector(Collectors.joining(","));
list.stream().map(item -> item.field2)).collector(Collectors.joining(","));
list.stream().map(item -> {
         //some complex parser function
    })).collector(Collectors.joining(","));
...

//pseudocode
private String map(List<MyObject> list, Function func) {
    return list.stream.map(item -> func.call()).collector(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

**Update**:

what if the object type changes? I still want to have my general `map()` method that defines the collecting of the extracted field. But as the object type changes, I just want to supply a function that knows how to extract the desired property.

```
class Person {
    String name;
} 

class Car {
    String manufacture;
}

map(persons, (person) -> person.name));
map(cars, (car) -> car.manufacture));
map(cars, (MyObject) -> {
   //more complex parsing
}));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a `Function<MyObject, String>`:

```
private String map(List<MyObject> list, Function<MyObject, String> func) {
        return list.stream().map(func).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

**Update:**

here is a generic implementation:

```
private <T> String map(List<? extends T> list,  
           Function<? super T, ? extends CharSequence> func) {
       return list.stream().map(func).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Comment: That's nice. What if the object changes it's implementation not having an interface. Can I also provide the method extractor as a function then?

Comment: @membersound you can only pass a lambda, method reference where the target type is a functional interface with a matching function descriptor. maybe that didn't answer your question completely? if so can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I added an example in my question, maybe that's clearer now? I just noticed it's now just how to generalize the parsing of a specific list type. I just want to provide a map function, and pass in whatever listtypes I have, also providing the extraction strategy. Maybe with the use of generics?

Comment: Ok that was the missing piece :)

Answer (score 2):

> what if the object type changes? I still want to have my general map()
>   method that defines the collecting of the extracted field.

You're mostly looking for a generic approach here:

```
private <T> String map(List<T> list, Function<T, String> func) {
    return list.stream().map(func).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```